# Perl: can't load module because of wrong ELF class ELFCLASS64

Tags: perl, libxml2

I get the following error while trying to build code on a 64bit machine.

```
Can't load '/e/pkgs/linux/intel/perl/5.8.0/lib/site_perl/5.8.0/i686-linux/auto/XML/LibXML/Common/Common.so' 
for module XML::LibXML::Common: libxml2.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64  
at /e/pkgs/linux/intel/perl/5.8.0/lib/5.8.0/i686-linux/DynaLoader.pm line 229. 
at /e/pkgs/linux/intel/perl/5.8.0/lib/site_perl/5.8.0/i686-linux/XML/LibXML.pm line 11
```

The perl is 32bit, but I have both 32 and 64bit versions of libxml2.so.2 on my machine. Is it trying to use the 64bit version of libxml2?

Comment: I don't know how it works on unix. Is there a search path for dynamically linked libraries (.so)? If so, you mad need to change it so the 32-bit libxml2.so is found before the 64-bit one.

Answer (score 3):

The library you are failing to load is one that supports the Perl `XML::LibXML::Common` module, not the `libxml2` library. Most pure Perl modules are pretty portable across different versions of perl and even different platforms, but the binary files that sometimes support those modules are not, and you will get errors like this when you try to use a library that was built for one platform/version on another platform/version.

You will want to reinstall the `XML::LibXML` Perl distribution for your current system. Depending on how the wrong binaries got installed for your system, you may need to do this for several other distributions, too.

But before you do that, you might want to upgrade your version of Perl. Perl 5.8 is ancient, and Perl 5.8.0 is old even by the standards of Perl 5.8.

(running `cpan XML::LibXML` should reinstall that distribution for you)

Comment: Re "The library you are failing to load is [...] not the libxml2 library." Actually, it is. Common.pm is failing to load because Common.so is failing to load because libxml2.so is failing to load because libxml2.so is not the right type of binary.

Comment: @ikegami - is the presecription (reinstall `XML::LibXML`) correct?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know how the system determines which .so to load.